# Three.js add dynamic line(s) between animated sprites

Tags: javascript, three.js, line, sprite

I'm trying to add a line(s) between animated sprites, like in [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_sprites). I tryed different solutions. But I couldn't make a dynamic line and not even a static line between sprites that are animated. Is it possible to create a dymanic line between those sprites from that example. If yes, how can I do it?

This is the code I used:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();    
         geometry.vertices.push(objects.position);

          var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
                        color: 0x0000FF,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 1 
                    } );        
          var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces );
          scene.add( line );

}
```

On ...jsfiddle.net/LxpmN/40/ u can see what I'm try to achieve, but he used two meshes instead of sprites. I understand that I need to put `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`, but I can't even make a static line from objects, like in that previous example.

Comment: What renderer are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a collection of line segments to your scene, create one `THREE.Line` instead of many. Use a pattern like this one:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();    

for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length - 1; i ++ ) { // stop one short of end

    geometry.vertices.push( objects[ i ].position );
    geometry.vertices.push( objects[ i + 1 ].position );

}

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000FF } );

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces );

scene.add( line );
```

If you modify any of the object's positions, you will have to add the following line in the render loop:

```
line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Everything works fine untill I put `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` in `function render() {...`. After that I get a black screen. Here on http://jsfiddle.net/f7aok1y6/67/ you can see that your code is working, but after I put `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` in the render loop the screen goes black.

Comment: No, had errors before with `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`. I placed that line everywhere still didn't work, and I dont know why. Ill check the other jsfiddle.net/LxpmN/40/ to try to find out where the bug is.

Comment: The console tells you that `line` is not defined. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I added `var line` at top and it still didn't work. You can give a hint if u want or an example for me to learn from.

Comment: Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7aok1y6/124/.  (Yikes! Version #124 ? You do not need save a new version of the fiddle before you run it. )

Comment: Can you tell why `var` should have been removed? It's a bug? Do you know if its possible to create a line that will only be visible when other vertice(s) are too close to the other vertice(s), like the drawcalls example from three.js? Thanks again.

Comment: A bug? No. Read about Javascript and [local scope](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/). If you have more questions, you need to make a new post, and preferably, show what you have tried.